# JSONDecodeError: Expecting value line 6 column 1 (char 5) LSTM code

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, lstm

I have a JSON file in the same directory as my python script called config.json. Whenever I try to implement this code:

`configs = json.load(open('config.json', 'r'))`

or even this:
`with open('path_to_file/person.json') as f: data = json.load(f)`

I keep getting this error:

```
  ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
JSONDecodeError                           Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-20-25276c4d1646> in <module>
----> 1 configs = json.load(open('config.json', 'r'))
      2 

~\.conda\envs\Keras\lib\json\__init__.py in load(fp, cls, object_hook, parse_float, parse_int, parse_constant, object_pairs_hook, **kw)
    297         cls=cls, object_hook=object_hook,
    298         parse_float=parse_float, parse_int=parse_int,
--> 299         parse_constant=parse_constant, object_pairs_hook=object_pairs_hook, **kw)
    300 
    301 

~\.conda\envs\Keras\lib\json\__init__.py in loads(s, encoding, cls, object_hook, parse_float, parse_int, parse_constant, object_pairs_hook, **kw)
    352             parse_int is None and parse_float is None and
    353             parse_constant is None and object_pairs_hook is None and not kw):
--> 354         return _default_decoder.decode(s)
    355     if cls is None:
    356         cls = JSONDecoder

~\.conda\envs\Keras\lib\json\decoder.py in decode(self, s, _w)
    337 
    338         """
--> 339         obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
    340         end = _w(s, end).end()
    341         if end != len(s):

~\.conda\envs\Keras\lib\json\decoder.py in raw_decode(self, s, idx)
    355             obj, end = self.scan_once(s, idx)
    356         except StopIteration as err:
--> 357             raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
    358         return obj, end

JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 6 column 1 (char 5)
```

Any ideas?

json file:

```
{
    "data": {
        "filename": "sp500.csv",
        "columns": [
            "Close",
            "Volume"
        ],
        "sequence_length": 50,
        "train_test_split": 0.85,
        "normalise": true
    },
    "training": {
        "epochs": 2,
        "batch_size": 32
    },
    "model": {
        "loss": "mse",
        "optimizer": "adam",
        "save_dir": "saved_models",
        "layers": [
            {
                "type": "lstm",
                "neurons": 100,
                "input_timesteps": 49,
                "input_dim": 2,
                "return_seq": true
            },
            {
                "type": "dropout",
                "rate": 0.2
            },
            {
                "type": "lstm",
                "neurons": 100,
                "return_seq": true
            },
            {
                "type": "lstm",
                "neurons": 100,
                "return_seq": false
            },
            {
                "type": "dropout",
                "rate": 0.2
            },
            {
                "type": "dense",
                "neurons": 1,
                "activation": "linear"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

You can find the link to this practice assignment here too:
https://github.com/jaungiers/LSTM-Neural-Network-for-Time-Series-Prediction

Comment: Your json file is invalid, can you share it here, so we can point out the issue ?

Comment: This is the link to the practice assignment as well as the link to the github page of the author: https://www.altumintelligence.com/articles/a/Time-Series-Prediction-Using-LSTM-Deep-Neural-Networks  //  https://github.com/jaungiers/LSTM-Neural-Network-for-Time-Series-Prediction

Comment: Just add the json you're trying to decode to your question

Comment: Thank you, I did update my question now.

Comment: Are you sure it's the file you're trying to read ? because I can load it with any problem with `configs = json.load(open('config.json', 'r'))`

Comment: yeah, i just opened a new file in my jupyter and tried it again, it still gives the same error.  I would like to be able to do it on my jupyter notebook since I am used to it. (perhaps with a different IDE it works, havent tried it yet) Is there any way to perhaps create a new json file and use that instead with the existing code that I copied?

Comment: Sure, that's what I did. I copied your json into a `config.json` and opened it within a jupyter notebook.